# open selected class in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I participated in a lecture, where the lecturer used some kind of keyboard shorcut to open selected class in editor.

Selecting PostEntity with cursor like here:
[image]

Pressing the shortcut would result in PostEntity class file getting opened.

What is the shortcut?

Comment: You could have found [this handy overview](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) of IntelliJ shortcuts with a quick web search.

Comment: there's also a built-in "action" lookup you can activate with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`A` / `SHIFT`+`COMMAND`+`A` (if you know what you're looking for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have just found it, by default it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> button on Windows and <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> on OSX.

Comment: If you prefer not to use mouse at all, try Ctrl+B.

Comment: for interfaces: `CTRL`+`B` to go to the declaration, `CTRL`+`ALT`+`B` to go straight to the _implementation_